# Improve PSTricks code for drawing of a general, regular polygon

Tags: pstricks, code-review

Consider the following example.

**Code**

```
% pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-eucl,pst-poly,pstricks-add}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN
    \calc
  \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\OuterRadius{\calc{\SideLength/(2*sin(pi/\NoSides))}}
\def\RelativeAngle{\calc{360/\NoSides}}
\def\Rotation{\calc{\RelativeAngle/2}}
\def\Area{\calc{1/4*\NoSides*\SideLength^2*cot(pi/\NoSides)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
% Parameters
\def\NoSides{8}
\def\SideLength{60}
\psset{unit=0.05cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-\OuterRadius,-\OuterRadius)(\OuterRadius,\OuterRadius)
  \pscircle(0,0){\OuterRadius}
  \rput(0,0){%
    \PstPolygon[
      PolyNbSides=\NoSides,
      PolyRotation=\Rotation,
      unit=\OuterRadius,
      linewidth=2\pslinewidth
    ]
  }
  \multido{\rA=0+\RelativeAngle,\iA=1+1}{\NoSides}{%
    \psRelNode[angle=\rA](0,0)%
      (!180 \NoSides\space div cos \OuterRadius\space mul
        180 \NoSides\space div sin \OuterRadius\space mul){1}{P\iA}
  }
 \psset{linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,RightAngleSize=5}
  \rput(0,0){$A \approx \SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{\Area}{\square\m}$}
  % The (really) bad code starts here.
  \pcline[linestyle=dashed,offset=-8pt]{|-|}(P2)(P1)
  \ncput*[nrot=:U]{\SI{\SideLength}{\m}}
  \psRelLine[linestyle=none](P8)(P1){2}{S'}
  \psRelLine[linestyle=none](P3)(P2){2}{S''}
  \psIntersectionPoint(P1)(S')(P2)(S''){S}
  \pstRightAngle[linestyle=dotted]{P1}{S}{P2}
  \pcline[linestyle=dotted](P1)(S)
  \pcline[linestyle=dashed,offset=-8pt]{|-|}(P1)(S)
  \ncput*{$x$}
  \pcline[linestyle=dotted](P2)(S)
  \pcline[linestyle=dashed,offset=8pt]{|-|}(P2)(S)
  \ncput*{$x$}
  \psRelLine[linestyle=none](P2)(P3){2}{T'}
  \psRelLine[linestyle=none](P5)(P4){2}{T''}
  \psIntersectionPoint(P3)(T')(P4)(T''){T}
  \pstRightAngle[linestyle=dotted]{P3}{T}{P4}
  \psline[linestyle=dotted](P3)(T)(P4)
  \psRelLine[linestyle=none](P4)(P5){2}{U'}
  \psRelLine[linestyle=none](P7)(P6){2}{U''}
  \psIntersectionPoint(P5)(U')(P6)(U''){U}
  \pstRightAngle[linestyle=dotted]{P5}{U}{P6}
  \psline[linestyle=dotted](P5)(U)(P6)
  \psRelLine[linestyle=none](P6)(P7){2}{V'}
  \psRelLine[linestyle=none](P1)(P8){2}{V''}
  \psIntersectionPoint(P7)(V')(P8)(V''){V}
  \pstRightAngle[linestyle=dotted]{P7}{V}{P8}
  \psline[linestyle=dotted](P7)(V)(P8)
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Question**

I have the desired output but the code is not very elegant. The problem is (especially) to simplify the code giving the dotted lines and the right angle marks around the octagon.

**Update**

Code:

```
% pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-node,multido}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
% Parameters.
\def\NoSides{5 }
\def\SideLength{60 }
% Help.
\def\OR{\calc{\SideLength/(2*sin(pi/\NoSides))}}
\def\Area{\calc{1/4*\NoSides*\SideLength^2*cot(pi/\NoSides)}}
\edef\dAngle{\the\numexpr360/\NoSides}
\def\IR{\calc{1/2*\SideLength*cot(pi/\NoSides)}}
\def\LabelLine(#1)(#2)#3#4#5{%
  \pcline[linestyle=dashed,offset=#3]{|-|}(#1)(#2)
  \ncput*[nrot=#4]{#5}
}
\psset{unit=0.5mm}
\begin{pspicture}(-\OR,-\OR)(\OR,\OR)
 \pstVerb{/R \SideLength 180 \NoSides div sin 2 mul div def}
  \pscircle(0,0){!R }
  \multido{\iA=\numexpr\dAngle/2+\dAngle,\iB=0+1}{\NoSides}{%
    \pcline[linewidth=2pt](!R \iA\space PtoC)(!R \iA\space \dAngle\space add PtoC)
    \ifnum\iB=0 
      \LabelLine(!R \iA\space \dAngle\space add PtoC)%
                (!R \iA\space PtoC)%
                {-8pt}{:U}{\SI{\SideLength}{\m}}
      \LabelLine(!R \iA\space \dAngle\space add PtoC)%
                (!R \iA\space \dAngle\space add PtoC exch pop \OR\space exch)%
                {8pt}{0}{$x$}
      \LabelLine(!R \iA\space PtoC)%
                (!R \iA\space PtoC pop \OR)%
                {-8pt}{0}{$y$}
    \fi
  }
 \psset{linestyle=dotted}
  \psframe(-\IR,-\IR)(\IR,\IR)
  \rput(-\IR,-\IR){\psframe(5,5)}
  \rput(!-\IR\space \IR\space 5 sub){\psframe(5,5)}
  \rput(!\IR\space 5 sub -\IR){\psframe(5,5)}
  \rput(!\IR\space 5 sub \IR \space 5 sub){\psframe(5,5)}
  \rput(0,0){$A \approx \SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{\Area}{\square\m}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Problems:

I would like

- the polygon (here, pentagon) to be completely inside the dotted square,
- the dashed lines with the `x` and `y` labels to be placed as on Jubobs' TikZ solution.

**Update 2**

After Herbert's changes:

[image]

- I would like the "upper" dashed line to be horizontal,
- The polygon is still not completey inside the square.

If the problem in the second bullet is fixed, the problem in the first one will be fixed automatically (I think).

**Update 3**

Here is how I would like the square to be

[image]

(In the picture above, the square is drawn manually.)

Comment: Is it only about octagon? If it is for any polygon then constructing the outer square with 2 parallel sides is not generally possible.

Comment: @Bugbusters I had hoped for a general polygon. Can you then simplify the code giving the dotted lines and the right angle marks around the octagon specifically?

Comment: It is difficult to synchronize the dotted lines of frame with the ones of right mark angle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution without defining nodes. Works only for n=8:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}% for pdflatex --shell-escape
\usepackage{pst-node,multido}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\NoSides{8 }  \def\SideLength{60 }

\def\OR{\calc{\SideLength/(2*sin(pi/\NoSides))}}
\def\Area{\calc{1/4*\NoSides*\SideLength^2*cot(pi/\NoSides)}}
\edef\dAngle{\the\numexpr360/\NoSides}
\makeatletter
\def\LabelLine{\@ifnextchar[\LabelLine@i{\LabelLine@i[0]}}
\def\LabelLine@i[#1](#2)(#3)#4#5{%
  \pcline[linestyle=dashed,offset=#4]{|-|}(#2)(#3)\ncput*[nrot=#1]{#5}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5mm}
\begin{pspicture}(-\OR,-\OR)(\OR,\OR)
  \pstVerb{/R \SideLength 180 \NoSides div sin 2 mul div def
           /Q R \dAngle\space 2 div tx@Dict begin PtoC end pop def }
  \pscircle(0,0){!R}
  \multido{\iA=\numexpr\dAngle/2+\dAngle,\iB=0+1}{\NoSides}{%
    \pcline[linewidth=2pt](!R \iA\space PtoC)(!R \iA\space \dAngle\space add PtoC)
    \ifnum\iB=0 
      \LabelLine[:U](!R \iA\space \dAngle\space add PtoC)(!R \iA\space PtoC){-6pt}{\SideLength m}
      \LabelLine(!R \iA\space \dAngle\space add PtoC)(!Q dup){10pt}{$x$}
      \LabelLine(!R \iA\space PtoC)(!Q dup){-10pt}{$x$}
    \fi}
  \psframe[linestyle=dotted](!Q neg dup)(!Q dup)
  \rput(!Q neg dup)    {\psframe[linestyle=dotted](5,5)}
  \rput(!Q neg Q 5 sub){\psframe[linestyle=dotted](5,5)}
  \rput(!Q 5 sub Q neg){\psframe[linestyle=dotted](5,5)}
  \rput(!Q 5 sub dup)  {\psframe[linestyle=dotted](5,5)}
  \rput(0,0){$A \approx \SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{\Area}{\square\m}$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, your outer square is not similar to the questioner's one. How do you construct the outer square for `n=5` (for example)?

Comment: (1) I cannot compile using `pdflatex` (even if I add `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}`) -- should I upload the log file somewhere? (2) The outer square is not placed like in my drawing. (3) I would like to use `nrot=:U` for only the side length and one of the x's

Comment: @Herbert I have fixed (2) and (3) myself, but not (1).

Comment: for 1 I have to investigate and for 3 use `\def\LabelLine(#1)(#2)#3#4#5{%`and then `[nrot=#5]` and for the `\LabelLine` calls extend it with `{:U}` or `{0}`

Comment: for 1 move the line `\pstVerb{/R ...` into the `pspicture` environment

Comment: @Herbert Great! Btw. I have updated my question with a follow-up question.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: I updated my answer with all the changes and a correct square

Comment: @Herbert The square is not correctly placed, unfortunately. `:(` See updated question.

Comment: For n=8 it should, not? and How should the square be placed for n=5? Whith its center to (0,0)?

Comment: @Herbert For n=8 it works, indeed. See the updated question for how I would like the square.

Comment: @Herbert There is another problem with the code: If I try n=7, two of the line segments, forming the polygon, are not connected properly; an unwanted space occurs.

Comment: sure, it is a solution for n=8. All others need a _lot_ of extensions for the square

Comment: @Herbert Okay. What about the "unwanted space" problem?

Comment: where is an unwanted space?

Comment: Let n=7. Then there is an unwanted space between the top of vertical line segment and the one next to it.

Comment: rounding problems, I use only an integer for the angle step

Comment: @Herbert Can I make you update your answer? When I try (by replacing `\iA` by `\rA`), nothing changes.

Comment: It seems strange to me that `\curvepnode[plotpoints=<...>]` or `\curvepnodes[plotpoints=<...>]` need both `pst-plot` and `pst-node`. If `\curvepnode` and `\curvepnodes` are defined in `pst-node`, why isn't `pst-plot` loaded by default?

Answer (score 5):

I really don't understand the purpose of presenting the outer square especially for odd-side regular polygons. In this answer I omit the outer square.

### Single:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node,siunitx}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

% constants declarator
\def\LoadConstants{}
\newcommand\const[3][6]{%
    \edef\temporary{trunc(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
        \edef\LoadConstants{\LoadConstants
            \noexpand\pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}}%
                        \ignorespaces}

\psset{unit=1mm}

\def\polygon#1#2{%
    \def\points{}%
    \const[0]{NoSides}{#1}
    \const{SideLength}{#2}
    \const{OffsetAngle}{pi/NoSides}
    \const{OuterRadius}{SideLength/2/sin(OffsetAngle)}
    \const{Area}{1/4*NoSides*pow(2,SideLength)/tan(OffsetAngle)}
    \begin{pspicture}(-\OuterRadius,-\OuterRadius)(\OuterRadius,\OuterRadius)
        \LoadConstants
        \rput{!OffsetAngle RadtoDeg}(0,0){%
            \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\numexpr\NoSides+1\relax]{0}{360}{OuterRadius t PtoC}{P}
            \multido{\i=0+1}{\Pnodecount}{\xdef\points{\points (P\i)}}
            \expandafter\pspolygon\points}
        \pscircle[dimen=money-oriented-programmer](0,0){!OuterRadius}
        \psset{arrows=|*-|*,nrot=:U,linestyle=dashed,tbarsize=2pt 2}
        \scriptsize
        \pcline[offset=-6pt](P1)(P0)\ncput*{\SI{#2}{\cm}}
        \pcline[offset=5pt](P1)(P0|P1)\ncput*{$x$}
        \pcline[offset=5pt](P0|P1)(P0)\ncput*[nrot=0]{$y$}
        \rput(0,0){$A \approx \SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{\Area}{\square\m}$}
    \end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\polygon{8}{60}
\end{document}
```

### Multiple:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node,siunitx}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

% constants declarator
\def\LoadConstants{}
\newcommand\const[3][6]{%
    \edef\temporary{trunc(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
        \edef\LoadConstants{\LoadConstants
            \noexpand\pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}}%
                        \ignorespaces}

\psset{unit=1mm}

\def\polygon#1#2{%
    \def\points{}%
    \const[0]{NoSides}{#1}
    \const{SideLength}{#2}
    \const{OffsetAngle}{pi/NoSides}
    \const{OuterRadius}{SideLength/2/sin(OffsetAngle)}
    \const{Area}{1/4*NoSides*pow(2,SideLength)/tan(OffsetAngle)}
    \begin{pspicture}(-\OuterRadius,-\OuterRadius)(\OuterRadius,\OuterRadius)
        \LoadConstants
        \rput{!OffsetAngle RadtoDeg}(0,0){%
            \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\numexpr\NoSides+1\relax]{0}{360}{OuterRadius t PtoC}{P}
            \multido{\i=0+1}{\Pnodecount}{\xdef\points{\points (P\i)}}
            \expandafter\pspolygon\points}
        \pscircle[dimen=money-oriented-programmer](0,0){!OuterRadius}
        \psset{arrows=|*-|*,nrot=:U,linestyle=dashed,tbarsize=2pt 2}
        \scriptsize
        \pcline[offset=-6pt](P1)(P0)\ncput*{\SI{#2}{\cm}}
        \pcline[offset=5pt](P1)(P0|P1)\ncput*{$x$}
        \pcline[offset=5pt](P0|P1)(P0)\ncput*[nrot=0]{$y$}
        \rput(0,0){$A \approx \SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{\Area}{\square\m}$}
    \end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=5+1}{4}{\polygon{\i}{30}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No need to understand it. `:)` There is meaning behind the madness.

Comment: Btw. your code looks really nice.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: My philosophy is to avoid using `\space` because it makes the code look long, verbose and dirty.

Answer (score 4):

An incomplete TikZ solution but which is flexible in terms of the number of sides:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

% Disclaimer: I use \pgfmathsetmacro instead of \def
% to avoid conflicts with existing macros

% parameters for the regular polygon
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{4}                         % radius of circumcycle
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\N{5}                      % number of sides (best if >= 5)
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{360/\N}                      % twice the interior angle
\pgfmathsetmacro\area{.5*\N*\R*\R*sin(360/\N)}  % area of polygon
\pgfmathsetmacro{\side}{2*\R*sin(180/\N)}       % side length

% quantities relevant for drawing
\pgfmathsetmacro\firstangle{90+.5*\a}           
\pgfmathsetmacro\secondangle{\firstangle-\a}
\pgfmathsetmacro\thirdangle{\secondangle-\a}    
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastangle{-270+.5*\a}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\myshift{8}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    thick,%
    mylinestyle/.style={%
        |-|,%
        black!50,
        dashed,%
    },%
    mynodestyle/.style={%
        fill=white,%
        sloped,%
        pos=.5,
    }
]

    \coordinate (A) at (\secondangle:\R);
    \coordinate (B) at (\thirdangle:\R);

    % draw x line
    \draw[mylinestyle]
        ([yshift=\myshift] A) -- 
        ([yshift=\myshift] A-| B) node[mynodestyle] {$x$};

    % draw y line       
    \draw[mylinestyle]
        ([xshift=\myshift] A-| B) 
        -- ([xshift=\myshift] B) node[mynodestyle,rotate=90] {$y$};

    % draw side line
    \draw[mylinestyle]
        ([xshift={-\myshift*sin(360/\N)},   yshift={-\myshift*cos(360/\N)},] A) --
        ([xshift={-\myshift*sin(360/\N)},   yshift={-\myshift*cos(360/\N)},] B)     
        node[mynodestyle] {$\side \,\text{cm}$};

    % draw the circumcircle   
    \draw[thin,gray] circle (\R)
        node[black] {$A \approx \area \, \text{cm\textsuperscript2}$};

    % Draw the regular polygon
    \draw (\firstangle:\R)
        \foreach \x in {\secondangle,\thirdangle,...,\lastangle} {%
            -- (\x:\R)
        } -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Really nice! If no PSTricks solution appears, I'll accept this answer (unless a better TikZ solution is presented).